# Creating partition on existing mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, sharding

Below is my table structure,  150k records

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `join_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`join_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I am using mysql version : 5.5.41

Data report :

```
+------------+-----------+
| join_date  | count     |
+------------+-----------+
| 2015-05-01 |       100 |
| 2015-05-02 |       100 |
| 2015-05-03 |       100 |
| 2015-05-04 |       100 |
| 2015-05-05 |       100 |
| 2015-05-06 |       100 |
| 2015-05-07 |     67900 |
| 2015-05-08 |     30622 |
| 2015-05-09 |     10455 |
| 2015-05-10 |     40393 |
+------------+-----------+
```

When I try to execute below command

```
Alter Table employees  PARTITION by RANGE (TO_DAYS(join_date)) 
      ( PARTITION p1 values less than (TO_DAYS('2015-05-07')));
```

I get following error: *Table has no partition for value 736090*. Even if I have 600 records less than value 2015-05-07

Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: 40K rows is rather small for a partition.  How many days will you keep in the table?  It is inefficient to keep more than, say, 50 partitions.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for further advice, plus efficient code for adding a new partitions and dropping the oldest.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but i think you should try:

```
ALTER TABLE employees PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(join_date)) (
    PARTITION p1 values LESS THAN(TO_DAYS('2015-05-07')),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
);
```

Comment: Not Working. Now it gives me Table has no partition for value 736093

Comment: please try again, i fixed mistyping